# How to ignore a tracked file locally only

Tags: git

How do I ignore a file locally only, that is already on the index? I don't want to remove the file from the index, thereby affecting others. Things I have tried:

- added the file to .git\info\exclude
- git update-index --assume-unchanged myFile.json
- git update-index --skip-worktree myFile.json

both update-index commands give errors when the file has been modified and trying to switch branches.

```
$ git checkout myBranch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        myFile.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

This error is because "content safety is still a priority" according to [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit). Any ideas?

Comment: ...how would removing a file from the index affect any other file???

Comment: Removing the file from the index would affect other users, not files. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

The question becomes: *what do you **want** to happen to `myFile.json` when you check out some other commit?*

#### Background

Using `--skip-worktree` (don't use `--assume-unchanged` here, it's meant as a speed hack rather than an absolute directive; see [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/1256452)) tells Git that it should not be too concerned about the modifications to the work-tree file.  But ... they *are* modifications to the work-tree file.  Let's say the path for this file is *P*.  Git leaves the index version matching the `HEAD` commit—lets say that this is, or will be by the time we're looking at it, commit ID 1234567.  The work-tree version changes, and when you do various Git operations, it "skips the work-tree version" and just keeps using the index version of *P*.  This lets you modify the work-tree *P*, and even make new commits if you like, using the (unchanged) index version of *P*.

In any case, your work-tree version of *P* no longer matches your index version of *P*.  You are, as we noted, now on commit 1234567, i.e., `git rev-parse HEAD` produces that hash ID.

Now, though, we find that for Git to check out the other commit, i.e., to move `HEAD` from commit 1234567 to commit fedcba9 or whatever, Git will have to *replace or remove* the index version of *P*.  It could do that, but as it's currently coded, that would also replace or remove the work-tree version of *P*.

(Switching to some *other* other commit, such as say 8888888—a very lucky commit in China—might *not* need to touch the index version of *P*.  In this case, `git checkout` would be happy to switch `HEAD` to that commit, and then afterward, back to 1234567 again.  But fedcba9 is not so lucky.)

It's "safe" to replace or remove a work-tree version of *P* **if and only if** the index version of *P* matches the `HEAD` version of *P*, since then you can get that version of *P* back from the old `HEAD`, i.e., from 1234567 in our example.  But we've already declared that the work-tree version of *P* doesn't match the `HEAD` version.  The `--skip-worktree` flag does not change the (un)safety of *this* operation; it just means that various *other* operations don't complain that the work-tree version doesn't match the index version.

#### So, what do you *want* to happen to *P*?

You're sure, at this point, that you want to move from commit `1234567` to commit `fedcba9`.

Commit `1234567` holds a version of *P*, and your index version of *P* matches that.  Your work-tree version of *P* does not.

Commit `fedcba9` holds a different version of *P* or says that *P* should no longer exist, and your index version of *P* does not match that.

Checking out `fedcba9` will put `fedcba9`'s version of *P* into the index, or remove *P* from the index.  Either action *should* replace-or-remove the work-tree version of *P* as well so that you can see what's in (or not on) `fedcba9`.  It's definitely not the same as what's in `1234567`.

Would you *like* to see that version of that file?  If so, save the current work-tree contents of *P* elsewhere, restore *P* to what's in the index / HEAD commit, and then check out `fedcba9`.  You will now see, in the work-tree, what's in `fedcba9`.  Your saved-elsewhere *P* will be safe elsewhere.

Do you *not care* what's in that version of that file, and want to retain what's there now?  If so, save the current work-tree contents of *P* elsewhere, restore *P* to what's in the index / HEAD commit, and then check out `fedcba9`.  Then overwrite whatever is in the work-tree with your saved-elsewhere copy.

Git won't choose either of these for you, but it's easy to do yourself.  You just need to decide which one, and then do it.